# CloverETL: Compare two records

Tags: etl, cloveretl

I have two files, A and B. The records in both files share the same format and the first n characters of a record is its unique identifier. The record is of fixed length format and consists of m fields (field1, field2, field3, ...fieldm). File B contains new records and records in file A that have changed. How can I use cloverETL to determine which fields have changed in a record that appears in both files?

Also, how can I gather metrics on the frequency of changes for individual fiels. For example, I would like to know how many records had changes in fieldm.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical example of Slowly Changing Dimension problem. Solution with CloverETL is described on theirs blog: [Building Data Warehouse with CloverETL: Slowly Changing Dimension Type 1](http://blog.cloveretl.com/building-data-warehouse-scd1) and [Building Data Warehouse with CloverETL: Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2](http://blog.cloveretl.com/building-data-warehouse-scd2).